# Должна ли стоять запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

> Когда документы в руках дали 3 года отсрочки.

Answer (score 2):

Тут со временем нелады: главное предложение в прошедшем времени, придаточное - в настоящем. Нужно поставить сказуемое "дать" в настоящем времени:

*Когда документы в руках, дают три года отсрочки.*

(Можно перестроить предложение и иначе: *Если документы на руках, дают три года отсрочки.* Предлог "на" - канцелярит, но что поделаешь, устоявшаяся форма: *документы на руках*. К тому же в письменной речи числительные обозначают словом, а не цифрой.)

Ну какое тут "обстоятельство условия", как проинформировал нас Антон Логунов... Это СПП - сложноподчинённое предложение.

Первая основа - (они) дают, вторая - документы (есть) на руках.

Comment: Если очень сильно напрячь фантазию, то можно представить такую ситуацию, в которой оригинальная фраза может быть сохранена. Диалог: *- Помнишь тот случай? - Какой? - Когда документы в руках дали 3 года отсрочки.* И никаких запятых не надо!

Comment: В принципе - да. Но какая ж "нерусская" фраза!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что надо поставить запятую перед словом дали. Обстоятельство условия.